# jq - get dict element based on key regex

Tags: json, jq

I'm working with a JSON object having the following structure:

```
{
  "key-foo-1.0": [
    {
      "key1": "foo",
      "key2": "bar",
      "id": "01"
    },
    {
      "key1": "foo",
      "key2": "bar",
      "id": "23"
    }
  ],
  "key-bar-1.0": [
    {
      "key1": "foo",
      "key2": "bar",
      "id": "45"
    },
    {
      "key1": "foo",
      "key2": "bar",
      "id": "67"
    }
  ],
  "key-baz-1.0": [
    {
      "key1": "foo",
      "key2": "bar",
      "id": "89"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get all the `id` values where the "parent" key name matches the pattern `.*foo.*` or `.*bar.*`.

So in my example something like this:

```
cat json | jq <some filter> 
01
23
45
67
```

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443884/match-keys-with-regex-in-jq I tried:

```
$ cat json | jq 'with_entries(if (.key|test(".*foo.*$")) then ( {key: .key, value: .value } ) else empty end )'
{
  "key-foo-1.0": [
    {
      "key1": "foo",
      "key2": "bar",
      "id": "01"
    },
    {
      "key1": "foo",
      "key2": "bar",
      "id": "23"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I don't really know how to continue.

I also think there is a better/simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go with:

```bash
jq -r '.[keys_unsorted[] | select(test(".*foo.*|.bar.."))][].id'
```

```
01
23
45
67
```

This gathers all keys using `keys_unsorted`, then `select`s those matching the regular expression in `test`. The wrapping `.[…]` descends into them, the following `[]` iterates over the children, and `.id` outputs the values as raw text using the `-r` flag.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I wanted with clear explanations!

Comment: @iAmoric I just got aware that I have misread your regex in the question. The code markup for `.*bar.*` lacks a backtick which made the asterisks be interpreted as italics markup instead, so with the full stop at the end it got displayed as `.bar..` (which by accident produced the same result). Anyway, for the actual regex `.*foo.*|.*bar.*` note that using `.*` only makes sense if you further surround it with `^` and `$` to match the beginning and the end of the string, as `test` will not add them automatically. That said, to only test for arbitrary occurrences, just take the regex `foo|bar`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it. I saw it and fixed it on my side but it was just a detail. I still consider the answer valid :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following JQ expression:

```
jq 'to_entries[] | select(.key | test(".*foo.*|.*bar.*")) | .value[] | .id'
```

[JQ playground example](https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/?#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20%5C%22key-foo-1.0%5C%22%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key1%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22foo%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key2%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%20%5C%2201%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key1%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22foo%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key2%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%20%5C%2223%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22key-bar-1.0%5C%22%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key1%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22foo%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key2%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%20%5C%2245%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key1%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22foo%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key2%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%20%5C%2267%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22key-baz-1.0%5C%22%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key1%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22foo%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22key2%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%20%5C%2289%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%5D%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22filterExpr%22%3A%22to_entries%5B%5D%20%7C%20select(.key%20%7C%20test(%5C%22.*foo.*%7C.*bar.*%5C%22))%20%7C%20.value%5B%5D%20%7C%20.id%22%2C%22rawOutput%22%3Afalse%7D)